# R task, web scraping

Tags: r, function

I share my solution for the task, however, I get an error and cannot find the reason. Anyone can help with it?

1. Data download 1.1 Collect links Data on the Stack Overflow user survey is available on the Stack Overflow website. Create a web scraper that collects the links to the survey files. Select only the links to the surveys from 2017 to 2021.

```
lst_nodes <- "https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(".js-download-link")
lst_url <- lst_nodes[1:5] %>% 
  html_attr("href")
print(lst_url)
```

Complete the function to download the data files from the URLs that extracted.

```
fun_download <- function(url) {
  year <- # extract year from url   
  zip_file <- paste0("file_", year, ".zip")
  zip_dir <- paste0("dir_", year) 
  download.file(url, zip_file)
  unzip(zip_file, exdir = zip_dir, files = "survey_results_public.csv")   
  out <- read_csv(file.path(zip_dir, "survey_results_public.csv"), col_types = cols(.default = "c")) %>% 
    mutate(Year = year, ResponseId = row_number())
  return(out)
  year <- sub(".*[^0-9]([0-9]+)\\.zip$", "\\1", lst_url)
}
```

Apply the function to the URLs that you extracted and generate a data frame that contains the data from all surveys.
Save the data frame. Note: The read_csv command in the function seems to keep the downloaded csv files locked after reading. So once you tried to open the csv files, you cannot delete them. To overcome this lock, restart the R session.
Best to save the data so that you have to run the download and importing only once.

```
alldf <- lapply(lst_url, fun_download)
```

That is all I did so far...but it seems something is wrong

Comment: BTW, *"it seems something is wrong"* is a vacuous statement that does not help us understand *quickly* what is going wrong. It would be ***GREAT*** if you could include *what* went wrong. In this case, your `year <- #` is not syntactically wrong, but is a logical mistake: since `year` is not previously defined, `paste0` is using what is likely the `lubridate::year` *function*, which is a mistake. Had you included the actual error message(s) you see, that might have been more obvious. Regardless, your code is fixed in my answer, since `year <-` was the mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Somehow it didn't work and I found another solution.

Comment: You deleted your nearly identical previous question 45 minutes after asking this one, and in that time you found another method that works? Even if my answer does not mimic what you did, please either accept the answer or indicate clearly (for others and for me) why you are choosing to ignore it. (Note that "accepting" an answer does not require that you actually use it in production.)

Answer (score 1):

My [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772674/writing-function-in-r?noredirect=1#comment125115476_70772674) to use `year <- sub(.)` needs to be put in context of the function itself, using its `url` only. This works.

```r
fun_download <- function(url) {
  stopifnot(length(url) == 1L) # just a safeguard
  year <- sub(".*[^0-9]([0-9]+)\\.zip$", "\\1", url) 
  zip_file <- paste0("file_", year, ".zip")
  zip_dir <- paste0("dir_", year)
  download.file(url, zip_file)
  unzip(zip_file, exdir = zip_dir, files = "survey_results_public.csv")
  out <- readr::read_csv(file.path(zip_dir, "survey_results_public.csv"), col_types = readr::cols(.default = "c")) %>%
    mutate(
      Year = year,
      ResponseId = row_number()
    )
  return(out)
}

fun_download(lst_url[[1]])
# trying URL 'https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2021.zip'
# Content type 'application/zip' length 8825103 bytes (8.4 MB)
# downloaded 8.4 MB
# # A tibble: 83,439 x 49
#    ResponseId MainBranch   Employment  Country  US_State UK_Country EdLevel  Age1stCode LearnCode  YearsCode YearsCodePro DevType 
#         <int> <chr>        <chr>       <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr>        <chr>   
#  1          1 I am a deve~ Independen~ Slovakia NA       NA         Seconda~ 18 - 24 y~ Coding Bo~ NA        NA           Develop~
#  2          2 I am a stud~ Student, f~ Netherl~ NA       NA         Bachelo~ 11 - 17 y~ Other onl~ 7         NA           NA      
#  3          3 I am not pr~ Student, f~ Russian~ NA       NA         Bachelo~ 11 - 17 y~ Other onl~ NA        NA           NA      
#  4          4 I am a deve~ Employed f~ Austria  NA       NA         Master?~ 11 - 17 y~ NA         NA        NA           Develop~
#  5          5 I am a deve~ Independen~ United ~ NA       England    Master?~ 5 - 10 ye~ Friend or~ 17        10           Develop~
#  6          6 I am a stud~ Student, p~ United ~ Georgia  NA         Bachelo~ 11 - 17 y~ Other onl~ NA        NA           NA      
#  7          7 I code prim~ I prefer n~ United ~ New Ham~ NA         Seconda~ 11 - 17 y~ Other onl~ 3         NA           NA      
#  8          8 I am a stud~ Student, f~ Malaysia NA       NA         Bachelo~ 11 - 17 y~ School;On~ 4         NA           NA      
#  9          9 I am a deve~ Employed p~ India    NA       NA         Bachelo~ 18 - 24 y~ Coding Bo~ 6         4            Develop~
# 10         10 I am a deve~ Employed f~ Sweden   NA       NA         Master?~ 11 - 17 y~ School     7         4            Data sc~
# # ... with 83,429 more rows, and 37 more variables: OrgSize <chr>, Currency <chr>, CompTotal <chr>, CompFreq <chr>,
# #   LanguageHaveWorkedWith <chr>, LanguageWantToWorkWith <chr>, DatabaseHaveWorkedWith <chr>, DatabaseWantToWorkWith <chr>,
# #   PlatformHaveWorkedWith <chr>, PlatformWantToWorkWith <chr>, WebframeHaveWorkedWith <chr>, WebframeWantToWorkWith <chr>,
# #   MiscTechHaveWorkedWith <chr>, MiscTechWantToWorkWith <chr>, ToolsTechHaveWorkedWith <chr>, ToolsTechWantToWorkWith <chr>,
# #   NEWCollabToolsHaveWorkedWith <chr>, NEWCollabToolsWantToWorkWith <chr>, OpSys <chr>, NEWStuck <chr>, NEWSOSites <chr>,
# #   SOVisitFreq <chr>, SOAccount <chr>, SOPartFreq <chr>, SOComm <chr>, NEWOtherComms <chr>, Age <chr>, Gender <chr>,
# #   Trans <chr>, Sexuality <chr>, Ethnicity <chr>, Accessibility <chr>, MentalHealth <chr>, SurveyLength <chr>, ...
```

From here, use `lapply(., fun_download)` to produce a list of frames.

```r
list_of_frames <- lapply(lst_url, fun_download)
# trying URL 'https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2021.zip'
# Content type 'application/zip' length 8825103 bytes (8.4 MB)
# downloaded 8.4 MB
# trying URL 'https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2020.zip'
# Content type 'application/zip' length 9908290 bytes (9.4 MB)
# downloaded 9.4 MB
# trying URL 'https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2019.zip'
# Content type 'application/zip' length 18681322 bytes (17.8 MB)
# downloaded 17.8 MB
# trying URL 'https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2018.zip'
# Content type 'application/zip' length 20022841 bytes (19.1 MB)
# downloaded 19.1 MB
# trying URL 'https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2017.zip'
# Content type 'application/zip' length 9576818 bytes (9.1 MB)
# downloaded 9.1 MB
```

And a terse summary to show what they hold:

```r
lapply(list_of_frames, function(z) z[1:2, 1:4])
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   ResponseId MainBranch                             Employment                                           Country    
#        <int> <chr>                                  <chr>                                                <chr>      
# 1          1 I am a developer by profession         Independent contractor, freelancer, or self-employed Slovakia   
# 2          2 I am a student who is learning to code Student, full-time                                   Netherlands
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Respondent MainBranch                     Hobbyist Age  
#   <chr>      <chr>                          <chr>    <chr>
# 1 1          I am a developer by profession Yes      NA   
# 2 2          I am a developer by profession No       NA   
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Respondent MainBranch                             Hobbyist OpenSourcer            
#   <chr>      <chr>                                  <chr>    <chr>                  
# 1 1          I am a student who is learning to code Yes      Never                  
# 2 2          I am a student who is learning to code No       Less than once per year
# [[4]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Respondent Hobby OpenSource Country       
#   <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <chr>         
# 1 1          Yes   No         Kenya         
# 2 3          Yes   Yes        United Kingdom
# [[5]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Respondent Professional ProgramHobby Country       
#   <chr>      <chr>        <chr>        <chr>         
# 1 1          Student      Yes, both    United States 
# 2 2          Student      Yes, both    United Kingdom
```

If you need to assign names (such as the URL used to derive each dataset), then perhaps this, which adds a `$url` field to each frame.

```r
list_of_frames <- Map(function(x, u) transform(x, url = u), list_of_frames, lst_url)
```

---

Data

```r
library(rvest)
lst_nodes <- read_html("https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/") %>% 
  html_nodes(".js-download-link")
lst_url <- html_attr(lst_nodes [1:5], "href")
lst_url
# [1] "https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2021.zip"
# [2] "https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2020.zip"
# [3] "https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2019.zip"
# [4] "https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2018.zip"
# [5] "https://info.stackoverflowsolutions.com/rs/719-EMH-566/images/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2017.zip"
```

Comment: (I was 99% of the way through answering this when you deleted your previous question.)